# Adapt CSS sizes to specific mobile screen

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design

I'm using JavaScript to **dynamically** adapt sizes of CSS elements to specific mobile screen. Something like:

```
var MY_DESIGN_WID = 420;
var MY_ELEMENET_WID = 200;
var actualWid = window.innerWidth;
var id = document.getElementById('myElement');
id.style.width = Math.round(MY_ELEMENET_WID * actualWid / MY_DESIGN_WID) + 'px';
```

I'm doing this for every relevant size of my CSS elements... Isn't there a "nicer" way to achieve the same functionality?

Comment: Why are you doing it through javascript? Its better to do it through css media queries, see: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: And not just that, a combination of `%` values or `vw`, `vh` or `vmin` values and media queries would solve this and be a lot faster than using JS.

Comment: Depends on what the elements are. `width: 100%` usually does the job.

Comment: I guess using `%` makes lots of sense, except that I'm not sure I can use fractions, such as `left:27.112%` or `width:33.333%` ... can I?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript to achieve this but it would be alot easier and more supported through devices if you just do it in CSS using @media queries.

Javascript can be turned off in most devices and CSS is also hardware-accelerated so you will also see a marginal improvement in performance.

```
    #exampleDiv {
      width: 300px; // Set width 300px
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 768px){ //Apply conditions if screen width > 768px
      #exampleDiv {width: 500px;} // Change width to 500px
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use media queries, for screen management and some times for certain effects that are hard to achieve with CSS I use JavaScript. Both JavaScript and CSS have the same access to hardware graphic acceleration.

But this is certainly easy to fix with CSS adding a class that shows content depending on screen size.

You can find libraries like velocity js to do some animations in javascript, for example

http://julian.com/research/velocity/

I really like playing with velocity is nice simple and we'll documented.

Also sometimes accesing to certain properties of the geometry of an element can make again a layout so performance when animating things from JavaScript is a key value for smooth animations, you may search for layout trashing and repaint if you go this way.